# JavaScript: облегчат ли регулярные выражения решение задачи конвертации TeX в HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, tex

Допустим мы в рамках задачи конвертации TeX-разметки в HTML и рассматриваем замену TeX-макрокоманд в соответствующие им HTML-тэги с помощью `JavaScript`:

```
\textbf{пример 1} → <b>пример 1</b>
\emph{пример 2} → <i>пример 2</i>
```

Как Вы видите, в данной задаче нам нужно посредством строковых операцией найти каждую макроманду от `\` до `}`, но заменить не всё: слово между скобками должно остаться.

Я на данный момент довёл до рабочего состояния такой метод без использования регулярных вырженией:

1. Используя функции `JS` для работы со строками, находим позицию символа `\`.
2. Находим позицию первой открывающей фигурной скобки.
3. Вытаскивая подстроку между `/` и `{`, узнаём, что была за TeX-маркоманда (подразумевается, что у нас есть `switch-case` со всеми вариантами комманд, где мы указываем соответствие макрокоманд и имён HTML-тэгов).
4. Находим позицию закрывающей фигурной скобки
5. Вытаскивая подстроку между скобками, узнаём аргумент макрокоманды - это будет содержимое тэга.
6. Теперь заменить в исходной строке макрокоманду на HTML-тэг с содержимым не составит труда. 1-5 нужно будет повторить в цикле для всех TeX-комманд, содержащихся в исходной строке.

Даже если Вы не знаете TeX, то наверняка заметили, что в TeX-макрокомандах закрывающим символом является скобка, которая сама по себе в отличие от закрывающего HTML-тэга не даёт никакой информации об имени макрокоманды. Поэтому, заменять закрывающую скобку на закрывающий тэг нужно сразу, пока мы не перешли к следующей макрокоманде.

Можно ли решить эту задачу проще и помощью регулярных выражений? Под "проще" я имею ввиду глобавльную замену без перебора каждой TeX-комманды в цикле `while`.

P. S. Не нужно давать ссылок на готовые конвертеры TeX в HTML - на самом деле, мне ответ на этот вопрос нужен для решения другой задачи, не имеющей отношения к TeX. Просто конвертация TeX в HTML оказалась хорошей аналогией.

Comment: так может вы без аналогий  скажете что вам нужно, нет никакого смысла говорить про TeX не имея его ввиду.

Comment: У меня собственная `TeX`-подобная разметка, о которой кроме меня никто на данный момент не знает. Так что имеет.

Comment: Так у вам значит и парсер есть, а из парсера генераторы, напишите html генератор.

Comment: И всё же. Забудем то, зачем мне это нужно на время данного вопроса и просто рассмотрим этот как задачу.

Answer (score 0):

В простом случае поможет регулярное выражение: `/(\\(\w+){(.+?)})/`

Например:

```js
var text = '\\textbf{пример 1} \\emph{пример 2}';

var replacers = {
  textbf: function(content) {
    return `<b>${content}</b>`;
  },
  emph: function(content) {
    return `<i>${content}</i>`;
  }
};
console.log(text);
console.log(text.replace(/(\\(\w+){(.+?)})/g, function($0, $1, command, content) {
  var replacer = replacers[command];
  if (replacer) {
    return replacer(content);
  }
  return $0;
}));
```